# Efficiently initialize list of consecutively named variables for file import

Tags: import, initialization

Let's say I have the code:

```
     $runningLogFile0 = "m0.txt";
     $runningLogFile1 = "m1.txt";
     $runningLogFile2 = "m2.txt";

     If[FileExistsQ[$runningLogFile0], Get[$runningLogFile0], Print["Error: Noexist"];];
     If[FileExistsQ[$runningLogFile1], Get[$runningLogFile1], Print["Error: Noexist"];];
     If[FileExistsQ[$runningLogFile2], Get[$runningLogFile2], Print["Error: Noexist"];];
```

that I use to read in a list of consecutively named files, `m0.txt,m1.txt, m2.txt`. I want to make this code more efficient for reading in a large number of such files, for which it would be very tiresome to do in the above way.

Can I automate this with a `Do` or `Table`?

I thought something like

```
 Do["$runningLogFile" <> ToString[i] = "m"<>ToString[i]<>".txt";, {i, 1, 100}];
```

might work but apparently not.

Comment: Would ``Do[With[{file = ToExpression["$runningLogFile" <> ToString[k]]}, Set @@ {file, ToString[StringForm["m`1`.txt", k]]}; If[FileExistsQ[file], Get[file], Print["Error: Noexist"]]], {k, 5}]`` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to go about this is read in the file names - this way you don't have to explicitly check to see if they exist.

```
 path = SystemDialogInput["Directory", NotebookDirectory[]];
 fileNames = FileNames["*.txt", path];
 allFiles = Table[Import[fileNames[[num]]], {num, 1, Length[fileNames]}];
```

This reads the names of all files (in the specified `path` directory) that have the extension ".txt" and places the file names in a list called `fileNames`. It then reads all the files in this list. They can be be named anything at all, as long as they have the specified extension.

Of course you could use a different extension than `.txt`, you could specify the directory path in the code (instead of using the GUI), you can use `Get` instead of `Import`, and `Do` instead of `Table`. You could also filter out files you don't want before importing, if this is desirable.

Comment: Thanks, this works if you just have files called `0,1,2,3...` and change the code as: `fileNames = FileNames["*", path];
 allFiles = Table[Import[fileNames[[num]]], {num, 1, Length[fileNames]}];` but not otherwise as the files are not just named by numbers. Is there a way to concatonate `".txt"` onto `num` when you do the final read in?

Comment: You misunderstand how it works, I think. This reads the names of all files (in the specified directory) that have the extension ".txt" and places these names in a list called `fileNames`. Then you read in the files from this list. They can be be named anything at all, as long as they have the specified extension.

Comment: Based on the variable names used by the OP, should `Import` be used instead of `Get`?  It seems to me that unless the logfile has commands to be executed, `Get` should be avoided in this case.

Comment: @bill s Yes, sorry I was being an idiot. I think it did not work the way you had it because of `Import` vs. `Get` perhaps. My files contains lots of definitions like `f[2]=3.4234324, f[3]=3.35555533,....` etc and using Import for some reason did not set these in the workbook like normal, but when I changed to `Get` things are defined..

Comment: @bobthechemist @bill s I have no idea if using `Get` is dangerous here? It's just that using `Import` doesn't seem to set the definitions that I mentioned in the my previous comment.

Comment: @bobthechemist -- I'm not really sure what's in the files, so I added the suggestion of using `Get` in case this is preferable to `Import`. Either should work -- this just answers the part about getting all the file names... not what you're going to do with the information after it's read in!

Comment: @fpghost -- if you are going to be reading in definitions then `Get` might be better, but you also need to be careful about conflicting definitions.

Comment: @bills Do you mean if I have two contradictory definitions for, say, `f[2]` I will hit issues with `Get` but not `Import`? What is the behaviour of each in that case? thanks..

Comment: If you read in two definitions for the same thing, then you are going to have to be careful which one is in effect (probably the last one read and executed). I don't think there's anything wrong with this, but you need to be careful that subsequent code is using the definitions you think it is using.

Comment: @bills But how is that different to `Import`? Would `Import` produce an error instead or something?

Comment: One major difference is that when you `Import` using the above code, the imported information is assigned to allFiles[[1]], allFiles[[2]], etc. When you `Get`, the information is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a table:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
allfiles = Import[#] & /@ FileNames["*.txt"];
```